# Is there a default password of Kali Linux OS after first installation?

Tags: passwords, login

I installed Kali Linux OS on my hard disk and set nothing as username and password. Now at the time of login it ask for `localhost` username and password. I tried `root` and `toor` as default but didn’t worked for me.

Comment: How exactly did you install it?  If you're not using a LiveCD, then you were supposed to be asked to set the password during install. See http://docs.kali.org/frequently-asked-questions

Comment: @techie007 : At the time of installation, I haven't provided with any password. But anyway I solved the problem by resetting the root password via shell.Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 37):

I had the same issue. However I did remember entering a password and most default username for Debain flavors are root.

So try:

- **Username:** root
- **Password:** toor (or the password you entered at installation)

> Kali Linux Default root Password is toor
>
> **Default root Password**
>
> During installation, Kali Linux allows users to configure a password
>   for the root user. However, should you decide to boot the live image
>   instead, the i386, amd64, VMWare and ARM images are configured with
>   the default root password – “toor“, without the quotes.

Source [Kali Linux Default Passwords](http://docs.kali.org/introduction/kali-linux-default-passwords)

Comment: Yes, just use root and the password you used... Thank you @Benjamin

Answer (score 8):

Just encountered the same problem with a fresh Kali Linux install.
I chose to disable `root` login, and create a user account instead.
Don’t remember giving a `root` password

But here’s an easy workaround to jump straight into a `root`-shell without the password:

```
sudo su -
```

simple as that, now you’re free to change your root password:

```
passwd
```

Answer (score 3):

I went to boot menu and selected the “recovery mode.” There I used `passwd` command to set new credentials to my `root` account.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but tried something else. If you entered the `root` password at the beginning of installation then enter `root` as the user, and the `root` password you entered at the start of installation. That should work.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I had plugged in my username as `kali` during the installation, but it turned out that I had to use `root` as the username. The password was the one I set though.